# How to set some dummy value to Enum?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums

I am getting a value of an enum from foreach loop. These enum values were used in some loops. So I can't introduce new enum value. The code is below .

```
enum Appraiser{A11,A12,A13,A14};
Appraiser selected_Appraiser = null;
foreach(var key in AppraiserStruct.appraisers.Keys)
    if (selected_ComboBox.Text.ToLower() == key.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        selected_Appraiser = key;
        break;
    }
int min = dictionary[selected_Appraiser].min;
```

Now visual studio giving error as uninitialized variable selected_Appraiser is used.

1)But if I set selected_Appraiser to null. It is saying that null can't be assigned to value type.

2)If I made it as

```
Appraiser? selected_Appraiser = null;
```

then it is saying that Appraiser? cannot be converted into Appraiser. Can anybody say how to achieve this?

Note:I am using VS 2008 c# express edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve *cannot convert Appraiser? into Appraiser*: To read the value of a nullable variable use the value property. E.G. *selected_Appraiser.Value == Appraiser.A11*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) operator to assign the default value of `Enum` member

```cs
Appraiser selected_Appraiser = default(Appraiser);
```

It'll set `selected_Appraiser` to first `Appraiser` member, which is `A11`. Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

> The default value of an enumeration type E is the value produced by
>   expression (E)0, even if zero doesn't have the corresponding enum
>   member.

By default, the constant values of enum members are of type `int` and start with zero and increase by one following the definition order. You can also start a numeration from 1, if the constant value doesn't matter for you

```cs
enum Appraiser
{
    A11 = 1,
    A12,
    A13,
    A14
}
```

But the better approach here is to add to `Appraiser` some default value, like `None` and use it. It helps to ensure, that logic which finds some value works properly, rather then uses the default value

```cs
enum Appraiser {A11, A12, A13, A14, None};
Appraiser selected_Appraiser = Appraiser.None;
...
//value is found
if(selected_Appraiser != Appraiser.None)
{
}
```

Comment: `default` is also valid in newer C# versions.

Comment: @UweKeim `default` literal is C# 7.1 feature, `default(T)` exists from C# 2 or 3, IIRC. I don't think that VS 2008 c# express edition (as OP mentioned) supports the newest features

Answer (score 0):

`Appraiser` enum uses `int` an underlying type by default, and has named values from 0 to 3:

```
enum Appraiser
{
    A11, // 0
    A12, // 1
    A13, // 2
    A14  // 3
};
```

You can choose another unused `int` value and cast to `Appraiser`. It doesn't have to be named.

```
Appraiser selected_Appraiser = (Appraiser)(-1);
```